# Android json parsing by category wise

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have a Json Array like below:

```
[{"item":{"category Name":"T-e-PBS","SubCategory Name":"T-e-PBS"}},
{"item":{"category Name":"T-e-PBS","SubCategory Name":"Animals"}},
{"item":{"category Name":"T-e-PBS","SubCategory Name":"Birds"}},
{"item":{"category Name":"T-e-PBS","SubCategory Name":"Vegetables"}},
{"item":{"category Name":"T-e-PBS","SubCategory Name":"Colors"}},
{"item":{"category Name":"Rhymes","SubCategory Name":"Rhymes"}},
{"item":{"category Name":"Rhymes","SubCategory Name":"Animated Rhymes"}},
{"item":{"category Name":"Rhymes","SubCategory Name":"Cartoon Rhymes"}},
{"item":{"category Name":"Rhymes","SubCategory Name":"Prayers"}}]
```

I have tried but don't know how to get Category wise information as I have lots of Subcategories under Categories:

I want to Parse this JSON String and populate the data According to Category.

If I click on T-e-PBS button I should be able to get All Subcategories in a gridview like AnimalsImage, BirdsImages, etc in gridview.

And if I click on Rhymes category I should be able to get All Subcategories in a gridview.

Could anyone help?

I have tried:

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(json);
int size = ja.length();
Log.d("tag","No of Elements " + ja.length());
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String str = ja.getString(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap` of `ArrayLists`

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    try {

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(str); 
        // Where str is your response in String form
        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
            String category = item.getString("category Name");
            String subcategory = item.getString("SubCategory Name");
            ArrayList<String> categoryFromMap = map.get("category");
            if (categoryFromMap == null){
                // Not initiated
                categoryFromMap = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            categoryFromMap.put(subcategory);
            map.put(category, categoryFromMap);
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
// Accessing your data
for (String key : map.keySet()){
    // key contains your category names
    ArrayList<String> subcategories = map.get(key);
    Log.d("CATEGORY", key);
    for (String subcat : subcategories){
        Log.d("SUBCATEGORY", subcat);
    }
}
// Getting a single category
ArrayList<String> rhymes = map.get("Rhymes");
```

The Log.d sentences should give this output:

```
CATEGORY T-e-PBS
SUBCATEGORY T-e-PBS
SUBCATEGORY Animals
SUBCATEGORY Birds
SUBCATEGORY Vegetables
SUBCATEGORY Colors
CATEGORY Rhymes
SUBCATEGORY Rhymes
SUBCATEGORY Animated Rhymes
SUBCATEGORY Cartoon Rhymes
SUBCATEGORY Prayers
```

Answer (score 3):

In the for loop, retrieve required JSON Objects using

```
    JSONObject c = ja.getJSONObject(i);
```

And then store Json item in a variable using,

```
    String str = c.getString("category Name");
```

JSON Objects are represented using `{`. So depending on your JSON structure, parse it and retrieve desired item.

Answer (score 3):

**You can use HashMap to store the separate Category List, and you can easily get the desired list of Category like T-e-PBS, Rhymes, etc.**

```
// Which hold the category basis of category Type
HashMap<String, List<String>> category = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> cat_name = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> subcat_name = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    JSONObject script = new JSONObject("YOUR RESPONSE STRING");
    JSONArray listOfCategory = script.getJSONArray("YOUR_ARRAY");

    for (int j = 0; j < listOfCategory.length(); j++) {
        JSONObject item = listOfCategory.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("item");
        String cat = item.getString("category Name");
        if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("T-e-PBS")) {
            cat_name.add(item.getString("SubCategory Name"));
        } else if (cat.equalsIgnoreCase("Rhymes")) {
            subcat_name.add(item.getString("SubCategory Name"));
        }
    }
    category.put("T-e-PBS", cat_name);
    category.put("Rhymes", subcat_name);

    // To get the according to Category Name
    List<String> retrieveCatList1 = category.get("T-e-PBS");//Key is T-e-PBS
    List<String> retrieveCatList2 = category.get("Rhymes");//Key is Rhyme
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: What if you have more than 2 subcategories? will you add them to code with if clauses?

Comment: @santirivera92 i gave a way to solve the problem.. we can do it in multiple ways.. we can dynamically store multiple category.